# print Autoscaling group and AMI used by the instaces attached to the autoscaling group

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to programming, I want to print the Autoscaling Group and AMI of the instances attached to the Autoscaling group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using boto3

1. Get the autoscaling group: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.describe_auto_scaling_groups

```
response = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups(
    AutoScalingGroupNames=[
        '<your scaling group name>',
    ]
)
```

2. Get the name of the launch configuration. Response from above call looks like:

```
{
    'AutoScalingGroups': [
        {
            'AutoScalingGroupName': 'string',
            'AutoScalingGroupARN': 'string',
            'LaunchConfigurationName': 'string',
            'LaunchTemplate': {
                'LaunchTemplateId': 'string',
                'LaunchTemplateName': 'string',
                'Version': 'string'
            },
...
```

Get the name of the launch configuration (If you have only one autoscaling group with that name, the first result should the one you're looking for)

```
launch_config_name = response['AutoScalingGroups'][0]['LaunchConfigurationName']
```

3. Get the launch configuration: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.describe_launch_configurations

```
response = client.describe_launch_configurations(
    LaunchConfigurationNames=[
        launch_config_name,
    ]
)
```

4. Get the AMI name. The response from the last call looks like:

```
{
    'LaunchConfigurations': [
        {
            'LaunchConfigurationName': 'string',
            'LaunchConfigurationARN': 'string',
            'ImageId': 'string',
            'KeyName': 'string',
            'SecurityGroups': [
                'string',
            ],
...
```

If you lauch config name is unique then you can get the ImageId from the first entry in the list.

```
ami_id = response['LaunchConfigurations'][0]['ImageId']
```

This should be the AMI you're looking for. Keep in mind that in a stable state, all VMs in a scaling group will have the same AMI.